# Training of Conv2D model stuck [MNIST dataset]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator, mnist

As a part of a bigger project, I am writing a small Convolution 2D model to train a Neural Networlk on the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset.

My (classic) workflow is as follow:

1. Load the dataset and convert it to `np array`
2. Split the dataset into training and validation set
3. Reshape (`X_train.reshape(X.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)`) and one_hot_encode (`keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)`)
4. Get the model
5. Train it based on the data, and save it

My train function is defined as follow:

```
def train(model, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val):
    model.fit_generator(
        generator=get_next_batch(X_train, y_train),
        steps_per_epoch=200,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=get_next_batch(X_val, y_val),
        validation_steps=len(X_val)
    )

    return model
```

And the generator I use:

```
def get_next_batch(X, y):
    # Will contains images and labels
    X_batch = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 28, 28, 1))
    y_batch = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 10))

    while True:
        for i in range(0, BATCH_SIZE):
            random_index = np.random.randint(len(X))
            X_batch[i] = X[random_index]
            y_batch[i] = y[random_index]
        yield X_batch, y_batch
```

Now, as it is, it trains, but it hangs at the last steps:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/3
2018-04-18 19:25:08.170609: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
199/200 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss:
```

Whereas if I don't use any generator:

```
def train(model, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val):
    model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=(X_val, y_val)
    )

    return model
```

It works perfectly.

Obviously my method `get_next_batch` is doing something wrong, but I can't figure out why.

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: I don't think its stuck, you just don't give it enough time to go through the whole validation set. Try to set `validation_steps=2` to see if you can get through that stage.

Comment: You are absolutely right there. What would be a good value for the `validation_steps`? The naming changes with Keras2, but I don't know if ot has the same meaning as `nb_val_samples`.

Comment: The default process the whole validation step. How large is your validation set compared to the training set?

Comment: 80% training set `(48000, 10)` and 20% validation set `(12000, 10)`.

Comment: Well either you could be patient and or probably set them to half the size of the validation set (I think 6000 images should be enough for you to get an estimation epoch-by-epoch to get a feel on your model's progress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a huge validation set in your generator function. Look where these arguments are passed...

```
    validation_data=get_next_batch(X_val, y_val),
    validation_steps=len(X_val)
```

Let's say your BATCH_SIZE is 1,000. So you are pulling 1,000 images, and running through them 1,000 times.

So 1,000 x 1,000 = 1,000,000. That's how many images would be running through your network and that will take a long time. You can change the steps to a static number as mentioned in the comments, I just thought an explanation would help put it in perspective.